# Zip Files & Folders With No Base Directory

Tags: node.js, gulp, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda requires a zip file that produces a file when it's unzipped.

However, every node.js zip library produces a zip file that contains a base folder, containing the files Lambda needs, which breaks Lambda, resulting in a `'Cannot find module'` error.

For example, if I have a `index.js` file and a `node_modules` directory in the `dist` folder, when I use gulp-zip, I get an added root folder when the zip file is unzipped...

```
gulp.src(['./dist/**/*'])
        .pipe(zip('dist.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))

// When unzipped, this results in a "dist" folder containing index.js and node_modules
```

I've tried 6 node zip libraries and none have a simple way of excluding the base directory.

Any thoughts?

Comment: zip-gulp uses node-glob behind the scenes so I don't know if this helps at all:  https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob  See "ignore".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used 'node-archiver', which can zip a directory to a destination directory (which I just set as an empty string).

https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver#directorydirpath-destpath-data

```
var archiver = require('archiver');
archive = archive.directory('./directoryToZip/', '' ); //option 2 is the dest
archive.pipe(  outZip);
archive.finalize();
```